# Email SQL Result via SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server Query that needs to run every hour and sent me the count of the rows via email to me. The query will return only one row. This needs to be done via SSIS packages. I am not sure how to develop the package. I have seen certain articles but I couldn't find anything that could be helpful.

Articles that I have referred to are:

[How to control SSIS package flow based on record count returned by a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958244/how-to-control-ssis-package-flow-based-on-record-count-returned-by-a-query)

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/rowcount-for-execute-sql-statement.html

Comment: Why does it have to be an SSIS package. I email all the time from SQL Server.

Comment: How can you sent email from SQL Server?

Comment: You will want to do some research on the stored procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`. There is about 5 minutes of setup on the server (one-time) but it is very robust.