# Create a Variable in SSIS that retuns if a table is empty or not

Tags: sql, ssis

I would like create a variable in SSIS that retunr 0 if a table in SQL is empty and 1 if not.
I create THIS Variable with this code:

```
"DECLARE @is_empty int = SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [PAY_DWH].[dbo].[FCT_ADAPT_CASE]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
select @is_empty"
```

But the result is that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqJTq.png)
The result shoulb be 0 or 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Evaluate doesn't run the query, it just evaluates the expression. You need to actually run this in a execute SQL task. Also it could be a lot simpler, you don't need the `@is_empty` variable at all

Comment: oK, but How I run the query on variable section?

Comment: Here's a detailed answer on how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958244/how-to-control-ssis-package-flow-based-on-record-count-returned-by-a-query You would want to simply use  `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [PAY_DWH].[dbo].[FCT_ADAPT_CASE]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`